# CentOS 6.9 neither yum nor yum update working

Tags: linux, ping, centos6

I am absolutely new to Linux and VDS. The VDS's os is CentOS 6.9 . I am trying to install apache, mail server, php, mysql and so on. But to be able to install those `'yum update'` or `'ping google'` needs working, I think. I wonder what is the problem is. I have the following configurations and errors :
[image]

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that your link is down check ifconfig if there is any interface up

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your network connectivity? There could be many reasons for this error.

Try "ping 8.8.8.8" to make sure it's not a network connectivity issue.
Try "ping www.google.com" to make sure it's not a DNS related issue.

If they both work, there's probably an issue with your mirrorlist. Try "yum clean all" and "yum update".